# Fill certain indices of a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-indexing

I have a list of indices likes this:

```
selected_coords = [[1, 8, 30], [15, 4, 6] ,...]
```

And a list of values like this:

```
differences = [1, 5, 8, 2, ...]
```

Both have 500 entries. Now I want to fill a 3d numpy array with these values on the right index. What I tried to do is the following:

```
brain_map = np.zeros(shape=(48,60,22))

for i, index in enumerate(selected_coords):
    ind = list(map(int, index))
    brain_map[ind] = differences[i]
```

If I print the index and the value in this loop I get the right format, but if I print the matrix after the loop it seems like the values have been put in there multiple times instead of only on the specified indices. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wrote 30 in the first index as an example, I know this is out of range. This is not the case in the actual data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should avoid looping over numpy arrays whenever possible, otherwise you're losing performance. You can make use of [advanced ("fancy") indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to index a subset of elements at specific indices. This would work like so:

```
brain_map[ind_x, ind_y, ind_z] = vals
```

where `ind_x, ind_y, ind_z` and `vals` are all 1d array-likes of the same length. What you have is essentially the transpose of your index arrays:

```
brain_map[tuple(zip(*selected_coords))] = differences
```

The `zip(*)` trick essentially transposes your list of lists, which can then be passed as a tuple for indexing. For instance:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> M = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4)
>>> coords = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> tuple(zip(*coords))
((0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3))
>>> M[tuple(zip(*coords))]
array([ 0.12299864,  0.76461622])
>>> M[0, 1, 2], M[1, 2, 3]
(0.12299863762892316, 0.76461622348724623)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So essentially, apart from the bad practice of looping of arrays, the code didn't work because I did not use tuples for indexing?

Comment: @maxmijn advanced indexing can be really complicated in the general case. The short answer to your question is "yes": the basic (i.e. non-fancy) indexing scheme `M[i,j,k]` actually stands for `M[(i,j,k)]` due to python's implicit tuple syntax. If you use something other than a tuple (typically a list or an array) as an index, it might trigger fancy indexing. So `M[[i,j,k]]` gives you an array that contains `M[i]`, `M[j]` and `M[k]`, each implicitly corresponding to `M[i,:,:]`, `M[j,:,:]`, `M[k,:,:]`, respectively. Compare `M[0,1,0]` with `M[[0,1,0]]`, for instance. The latter is a 3d array.

Comment: brilliant.... I was stuck in a similar problem and zip(*) made my day....

Comment: @Piyush I'm glad it helped :)